# Create a Muriel-like language and implementation

Tags: code-golf, quine, language-design

[Muriel](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Muriel) is a language where the only way to loop is to create a quine and execute it. Your job is to create your own language with this property and an implementation of it in a pre-existing language.

We will define a Muriel-like language like as follows:

1. It has a built-in command for executing code in its own language, similar to Muriel's [`@`](http://web.archive.org/web/20020609004312/http://demo.raww.net:80/muriel/spec1.txt) command or python's [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/exec.html).
2. It is Turing complete.
3. If you remove the built-in execution command it is no longer Turing complete.

Muriel is Muriel-like with `@` as its built-in execution command. [Smurf](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Smurf) is also Muriel-like (its built-in execution command is `x`). Python is *not* Muriel-like, since it is still Turing complete if you remove `exec`.

Your job is to create a Muriel-like programming language, and then to provide an implementation of it in a language of your choice. Your score is the length of the implementation, which you are trying to minimize.

Notes:

1. Your built-in execution does not need to function exactly like Muriel. It is up to you how it handles termination of the child program, errors, scoping, etc...
2. The language you write the implementation can not *itself* be Muriel-like. (This is so that `@` is not a valid entry.) It also must have existed before this post.

Comment: Is [Underload](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Underload) a Muriel-like language?

Comment: @JerryJeremiah Does my edit make it clearer?

Comment: @alephalpha That wiki says "Without ^, the remaining program will always decrease in size, eventually halting." If this is true, then yes, Underload is Muriel-like.

Comment: What do you do if your target language has multiple `eval` commands? (Eg Python's `exec` and `eval`) Require the removal of all of them to lose TCness?

Comment: @PyRulez I think this should be [tag:popularity-contest] rather than code-golf, because otherwise the choice of implementation language would make it a chameleon challenge

Comment: @Uriel what's a chameleon challenge?

Comment: A challenge that looks like one thing (implement a language) but is another (choose your base language very carefully).

Comment: Could Brainfuck be considered Muriel-like, if you interpret all characters as appending themselves to the top of a “loop stack” (separate from the memory), `[` pushing a new empty string if the memory cell is truthy, and `]` popping and evaluating?

Comment: @xigoi I think with that description, technically yes, lol. I suppose all programmable computing is about code executing other code, when you think about it.

Answer (score 3):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) and "The minimum TC subset of Underload but with the characters changed to `2019`<s>, reversed, and with a `0` on top</s>", <s>156</s> 129 bytes

```python
c,n,*s=input(),0,[]
while c:
 i,*c=c;q="6">i
 if n:n+=q*int(i)-q;s[n and-1]+=i,
 elif q:n="1"<i;s+=s[-1]*(1-n),
 else:c=s.pop()+c
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XVOxctswDN35FThzkWwlJ7l37cWp2qVLpw5pJ50HmoJsXmRSJikn@XoXoC1dzpNI8AEPDw8aPuLB2S8X@YIInXMRPX08jHbv@g5bULYF7Y5HtBH51OKjEPKXigpMgBCdp7CxoOis9KuQaz74GCiy6x1HSkDbfrpX0I5Db7SKGODvnxchn0ANQwLRFaJLPEL@G9qE4YbiAWFdrkuq4xGsizC4EMyuR6qGnMOI1o0UaWEt5G8b0BPKGxszU@giFDYH1bFCUyx1rZ9P9eLr4odJ9VvcjXsS0rmLLmyxDLWxwxizvCiLZiveDoaY9Ebc5Yo7AnrvwG7sqj4tUzx/OD2HxvIcH6rtqjaFAOwJdNrYelEtvpvnsKpDQ4/LrHqweXoPuNF1eBzckOUrfbkTITtPbqWOBb6bmJUUGzyeySQaA/nSeXcEP1pr7F4IPWkBmQZr6xJkiFR0DxZD5G/GL5N1Nz8ZkItQN812ywns7zQIkNcTTZ38IMqUTzYQ6zQkkEd3ThDojA8R9EF5cN2MNZAZSzyjjsaRdFB9YPPtGbkNzZjehChgskqq3Y6EGsUJt2GD/NTvTwEUTWB24eZBBfJADlC/s941qdQeVcBQQEnTnC8VvCIOdODd/8ba8F33Y4ttnooTZfJrVTeG5kKBT/zFbZVJGzXP2w1XP0NTThmOh/ZmAs5ggrbj8fhBUORfTcwarnJ4T2hfKt6V2Q3a7ivnREG@JkDqjjDzb3bt436tQOJZ9Zd1VVZPT/8B)

Explanations in the header, ungolfed code in the footer.

Comment: RIP [grand chart](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12976/what-are-the-relationships-between-programming-languages-created-by-ppcg-users/12978#12978)

Answer (score 1):

## CJam, [CFU](https://esolangs.org/wiki/CJam-Flavored_Underload) analogue of the `():~^` subset of Underload, 12 bytes

```
q_"_\~\""--~
```

CJam already happens to be a stack-based language with an eval instruction, which makes it a good candidate for having a Muriel-like subset.

In particular, we define a subset with the following instructions:

- `"..."`: Push a string `...` to the stack. Quotes and backslashes inside the string can be escaped using backslashes. Equivalent to Underload's `()`.
- `_`: Duplicate the top stack value. Equivalent to Underload's `:`.
- `\`: Swap the top two stack values. Not strictly necessary for Turing-completeness, but we need to permit backslashes anyway. Equivalent to Underload's `~`.
- `~`: Execute the top stack value. Equivalent to Underload's `^`.

Explanation of the code:

```
q            | read input
  "_\~\""-   | remove all these characters: "_\~
 _        -  | remove all characters in the resulting string from the input
           ~ | execute the result
```